# How do I access a const volatile std::array?

Tags: c++, constants, volatile

I am trying to create a volatile array and I need to access it using operator [].

I find no way to do that for std::array, however built-in arrays work fine.

With GCC 8.2.0 the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main()
{
    const volatile std::array<int,2> v = {1,2};
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl ;
}
```

gives

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:6:21: error: passing 'const volatile std::array<int, 2>' as
'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

 std::cout << v[0] << std::endl ;

                 ^

In file included from <source>:2:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/array:185:7: note:
in call to 'constexpr std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type& std::array<_Tp, 
_Nm>::operator[](std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type) [with _Tp = int; long 
unsigned int _Nm = 2; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::reference = int&; 
std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type = int; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = 
long unsigned int]'

   operator[](size_type __n) noexcept

   ^~~~~~~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

while

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const volatile int v[2] = {1,2};
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl ;
}
```

works perfectly fine.

How do I access a const volatile std::array?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you need a volatile array to begin with?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm writing a code that needs to calculate somewhat complex things with std::array at compile time and investigating the generated assembly. I use volatile to force the compiler to create the std::array even if I don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

`std::array` has two overloads of `operator [](size_t)`. One for `*this` is const, one if `*this` is non-const.  Neither of these will work for you - because `*this` is const volatile.

If you use a `const_cast` to remove the volatile qualifier the result will probably compile, and it might even appear to work.  However the actual result is undefined behaviour (because the underlying object actually *is* volatile); that means it will stop working when you come to do the important demo to the customer.

For the language lawyers: [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) is the last committee draft of the standard before C++14.  Section 7.1.6.1 [dcl.type.cv] para 6 says:

> If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined".

I am pretty sure that similar language exists in all versions of the standard.

---

If you are using `volatile` to support multi-threading - please don't.  It doesn't actually help.  You need to use `std::atomic` or `std::mutex` to do that.  Volatile is useful to model special registers in a microprocessor address space.

Comment: What's the requirement for using a reference that's had `volatile` casted away? For `const` you can use that reference as long as you never "modify" the object, but what about `volatile`?

Comment: Would you mind adjusting your third paragraph as using `const_cast` would be a very bad idea? I'd upvote if you did that?

Comment: @Bathsheba - better?  It was *meant* as "don't even think about doing this" - but I forgot that most people aren't as allergic to UB as me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : Phew!  In [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)  7.1.6.1 [dcl.type.cv] para 6 it is explicitly called out:  "If an
attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with
a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined".  I am pretty sure that similar language exists in all versions of the standard.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thank you. Your answer works. I know it is dirty, it is not for deliverable code, just for some experiments with complex compile time algorithms where I have to use `volatile` to see some variables while investigating the assembly.

Answer (score 4):

`const volatile int v[2]` is an array of two const volatile `int`s, not a const volatile array of two `int`s.

Using a similar `std::array` compiles:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<const volatile int, 2> w = {1,2};
    std::cout << w[0] << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I happen to have a function `std::array<double,2> f()` and I assign in the following way `const volatile auto x = f();`, so `const_cast` even though dirty, is more appropriate for my application.